# Add Existing Function to DOM Element

Tags: javascript

I have a reference to a DOM element. I know I can add a function to it as in the following example where the function foo is added:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
    function bar() {
        console.log("inside bar");
    }
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    myDiv.foo = function () {
        bar();
    }
    myDiv.foo();
</script>
```

Invoking myDiv.foo() executes the document-level function bar() as expected.

What I would like to know: is it possible to add the document-level function bar as a member of myVar? So that I can call myDiv.bar() directly? The key is that bar would have to be able to access members of myDiv using the key word "this". I'm aware I could change bar to accept myDiv as a parameter and access its members that way, but I'm really interested to know if the specific approach I am asking about is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the child nodes of myDiv, with `access members of myDiv`?

Comment: `foo` is not properties of myDiv so why are you using `myDiv.foo`?

Comment: @RuhulAmin — `myDiv.foo =` will add a property to an object.

Comment: Why is this down-voted? The question was legitimate and the working answer is below!!!

Comment: Ruhul it is a member. I made it one. See the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign the function instead of creating a new one.

```
myDiv.foo = bar;
myDiv.foo();
```